# Mute a mysql warning message: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, vagrant

The MYSQL 5.6 & 5.7 keeps showing an annoying message

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure
```

in the vagrant/cygwin/ local environment's command line.  If I run it in an Amazon EC2 instance with a command line, the MySQL won't return this warning at all.  Is there any way to turn off this warning?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was also seeking for a solution for this . All I could come up with was:

```
mysql -u root -p"password" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem!

Have you seen this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html ?

You could easily save your credentials and use them with :

```
mysql -G your_conn_name
```